# Query malfunction in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am not sure how to describe it. I will call it "Query malfunction" for now.
If someone knows this, please edit my description.

I was quite happy with query function, but it seems it doesn't work on this one.
I used the same formula for `STORE1` and `STORE2` except the sheet name. But only with `STORE2` it is working normally.

Please check the picture and the sample([Sample Query malfunction](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/181Q_ybLpZ_Fw_sa6Xp2yD9Z3s5Y_sUyxYsxLpLTpWJs/edit?usp=sharing)).

[image]

---

Comment: Please share the spreadsheet itself, not the html-version of it.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the link, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't see the complete formula, but try adding a zero as the third parameter.

```
=QUERY(STORE1!C2:F, "your_select_clause_here", **0**)
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Sorry about the html link. I have changed the link! Now it works after I changed the formatting. @Mike Steelson mentioned on the other answer that formatting is mixed,. So I changed the formatting and now it is good!

Comment: Hey the 0 on the third parameter directly solved the problem. Could you share the reason?

Comment: If you omit the third (optional) parameter the function 'guesses' if a header row must be returned. Sometimes that guess is correct, sometimes it's not. To prevent this, always use the headers argument!

Answer (score 1):

Query doesn't work properly when a column has a mix of text and numeric values. To solve your problem, try

```
=QUERY(arrayformula(to_text(STORE1!C2:F)),"select Col1, sum(Col4) where Col4 is not null group by Col1")
```

Comment: I changed the formatting, now it works. But I'll take your formula for other applications. Thanks!